# What is the effective way to practice spelling for new words

Tags: spelling

I'm learning GRE vocab and they are quite a lot. Roughly in the range of 1000-3000 words. Reading, probably, is the most effective way to gain new words and reinforce them but I'm facing an issue with the spelling. At this moment, I type them in Word Office over and over. I would like to see alternatives for such practice to ameliorate my spelling skill. Could you provide some hints? I'm willing to pay if there is such services that allow me to add new vocab and test me via simple software where some one read them and I type them.

Comment: You may want to ask this question on the ELL Meta.

Comment: For myself, I can remember the spelling of new words in a foreign language better by writing them with pencil and paper than by typing them.